# View not centered in fragment in ViewPager and RecyclerView Hidden by Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager integrated with a TabLayout that displays 4 fragments (4 tabs). Each of those fragments are RecyclerViews that display lists of items. The number of items in each list is generated by a given date but sometimes there will be no items displayed. When this happens I switch to another fragment that displays in a TextView "No Games Scheduled".

The problem is that text is not centered in the screen. It is positioned kind of in the center but towards the bottom. I believe it has to do with my ViewPager attribute in XML where I set it to `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` (Note: this line is not displayed in posted code. I explain later.)

When I click on the xml code for the ViewPager, in the preview screen, (in Android Studio) the blue section that lights up is extended below the screen. So I know it has to do with that. When I remove that line of code the blue section fits the screen. As a test, I set the TextView displaying "No Games Scheduled" `layout_gravity` to `center|bottom` and when I ran the app, the text was not showing on screen. So I know it's being hidden by that line of code in the ViewPager. But I need it because I want the toolbar to hide when scrolling down and show when I scroll up.

I then tried removing `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from the ViewPager and placed it in each of the fragments. It works but now the top of each fragment is being covered by the Toolbar and the Tabs like this (not my program, because I'm not allowed to show the UI, but it shows my exact problem):

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help!

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/light_black"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/league_and_date_title_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/league_title_header"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    tools:text="League"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|end"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/previous_date_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/prev_date_button"
                        android:src="@drawable/previous_arrow"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/display_date_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/outnix_orange"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        tools:text="Date Goes Here"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/next_date_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/next_date_button"
                        android:src="@drawable/next_arrow"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading_circle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

One of the fragment's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/all_games_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_black"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Fragment I switch to when no items are in the RecyclerView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/no_games"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @DanielNugent This doesn't work (hiding the toolbar on scrolling works though) because when I set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in my ViewPager, it adds extra space below the screen, so when I switch to the fragment that displays "No Games Scheduled", the text is not centered even though I have programmed it to be centered. I'm trying to avoid adding padding or some similar hack because I want to it to be compatible with all kinds of devices as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that only works if all of your Fragments in the ViewPager scroll vertically.  Can you show a screenshot of the "No Games Scheduled" screen with the problem?

Comment: @DanielNugent I know it has to do with the fact that `CoordinatorLayout` is a FrameLayout. I could easily fix it by wrapping it in a vertical LinearLayout and placing the ViewPager below it but then the toolbar hiding on scroll doesn't work :/

Comment: @DanielNugent I can't display the UI but it's pretty clear the text is not in the center. When I set the text to the bottom of the fragment, the text is not displayed because it's below the screen.